# Simple Flume agent hat some lag when logging to the console

Tags: docker, docker-compose, flume

I have a simple Flume agent with the following configuration:

```
agent.sources = http-source
agent.sinks = logger-sink
agent.channels = logger-channel


# HTTP Source
###############################
agent.sources.http-source.type =  org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
agent.sources.http-source.channels = logger-channel
agent.sources.http-source.port = 81


# Logger Sink
###############################
agent.sinks.logger-sink.type = logger
agent.sinks.logger-sink.channel = logger-channel


# Channel
###############################

agent.channels.logger-channel.type = memory
agent.channels.logger-channel.capacity = 1000
```

The only thing that the Flume agent does, it to receive the HTTP POST request through the HTTP Source and logs the events using the Logger Sink.

The problem that I have is as follows: sometimes when I send the HTTP POST request to the Flume agent, It takes 1-5 second till I see the logs in the console. This is only the case for the first message being sent after starting the Flume agent. After sending several messages I see the logs immediately in the console.

My question is: is it a warm-up issues in Flume? It seems that if I do not send any message for a while, again I will have some delay seeing the logs in the console.

Notice that I start the Flume agent in a Docker container using a docker-compose file.

Comment: What happens when you launch is outside docker? You should compare with and without docker

Answer (score 1):

First check if the issue persists with the latest Flume agent available (release 1.7), using a recent image like [`mrwilson/docker-flume`](https://github.com/mrwilson/docker-flume).
You can compare its [`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/mrwilson/docker-flume/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) with yours.

An  image like [`gilt/docker-flume`](https://github.com/gilt/docker-flume) is older and still in 1.5.